# rviz does not display the urdf model after running the launch file

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### My System Specifications ##

1. Oracle VirtualBox
2. Ubuntu 18.04
3. ROS Melodic 1.14.3
4. Host Computer- Windows 10 with Intel i7 and Nvidia 1660 graphics

I have been following the tutorials in the book "Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming" by Lentin Joseph. In chapter 2,  for URDF tutorial, I did exactly follow the steps mentioned.

### STEPS

1. I created my pan & tilt model package inside the 'src' folder in my catkin workspace. 
   ~/catkin_ws/src $  catkin_create_pkg pan_tilt_model roscpp rospy tf geometry_msgs urdf rviz xacro
    2. Inside the pan_tilt_model package, I created three new folders, namely 'launch', 'meshes' and 'urdf'.<BR>
   ~/catkin_ws/src/pan_tilt_model $ mkdir meshes launch urdf
2. Inside the 'urdf' folder, I created my URDF file named 'pan_tilt.urdf'
   ~/catkin_ws/src/pan_tilt_model/urdf $ gedit pan_tilt.urdf
    4. Inside the 'launch' folder, I create my launch file named 'pan_tilt.launch'<BR>
   ~/catkin_ws/src/pan_tilt_model/launch $ gedit pan_tilt.launch
3. I tried to run the 'roslaunch' command to run the launch file for the pan & tilt model
   ~/catkin_ws $ roslaunch pan_tilt_model pan_tilt.launch

---

### Expected Outcome

Rviz should display my pan & tilt model in its display area along with a joint_state_publisher GUI.

---

### Outcome I got

Rviz didn't display my model in its canvas. It just displayed a blank grid. Also, rviz was showing errors as

- Global Status: Error
- Fixed Frame- Fixed Frame [map] does not exist.

---

I have attached the screenshot the rviz window I am getting in the below link.
[rviz_window](https://photos.app.goo.gl/VRByThv7Bf7cmMSF7)

---

**Launch File 'pan_tilt.urdf'**

```
<launch>
<arg name="model" />
<!-- Parsing xacro and setting robot_description parameter -->
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find pan_tilt_model)/urdf/pan_tilt.urdf" />

<!-- Setting gui parameter to true for display joint slider -->

<!-- Starting Joint state publisher node which will publish the joint values -->

<!-- Starting robot state publish which will publish tf -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
<!-- Launch visualization in rviz -->
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find pan_tilt_model)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
    <node name="jsp_gui" pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" type="joint_state_publisher_gui" />
</launch>
```

---

**URDF File 'pan_tilt.urdf'**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="pan_tilt">

  <link name="dummy">
   </link>

  <joint name="dummy_joint" type="fixed">
     <parent link="dummy"/>
     <child link="base_link"/>
   </joint>

  <link name="base_link">

    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.01" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="yellow">
        <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.03" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
    <mass value="1"/>
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="pan_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="pan_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
    <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="pan_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.06"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
    <mass value="1"/>
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="tilt_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="pan_link"/>
    <child link="tilt_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-4.64" upper="-1.5"/>
    <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="tilt_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="green">
        <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.06"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
    <mass value="1"/>
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>


</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353070/rviz-does-not-display-the-urdf-model-after-running-the-launch-file/) by [nilutpolkashyap](https://answers.ros.org/users/55179/nilutpolkashyap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please read: 7. Coordinate Frames and watch the video there. http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2020-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nilutpolkashyap](https://answers.ros.org/users/55179/nilutpolkashyap/) on 2020-05-24**:
Thanks a lot. It solved my problem.

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-28**:
You are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct to keep answers.ros organized. thanks.